# Snowflake's get_ddl displays extra single quotes everywhere

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, when I create a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure stack_overflow_question(select_table varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
as
declare
    select_statement varchar;
begin
    select_statement := '
        SELECT * FROM ' || :select_table || '
    ';
end;
```

Then, later when I use `select get_ddl('procedure', 'stack_overflow_question(varchar)');` function to make edits to the stored procedure, the result of this function call has extra single quotes.

Here is the result

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "STACK_OVERFLOW_QUESTION"("SELECT_TABLE" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 'declare
    select_statement varchar;
begin
    select_statement := ''
        SELECT * FROM '' || :select_table || ''
    '';
end';
```

Note the difference between the two! The extra single quotes. Also double quotes in the name of the stored procedure.

Is there something that I can do to prevent this from happening? I am using Snowsight - but don't think that this actually is the problem. Also, I am using snowflake as the language for stored procedures.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has all to do with how identifiers are done in Snowflake. Have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)

Comment: I don't think that this is related - only in the table name and args. I think that the single quotes within the body of the store proc is a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a UDF that you can wrap around get_ddl that will convert the DDL from using doubled single quotes to single quotes and wrap the body with $$:

```
create or replace function CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(CODE_TEXT string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    var lines = CODE_TEXT.split("\n");
    var out = "";
    var startCode = new RegExp("^AS '$", "ig");
    var endCode = new RegExp("^'\;$", "ig");
    var inCode = false;
    var isChange = false;
    var s;
    for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        isChange = false;
        if(!inCode) {
            inCode = startCode.test(lines[i]);
            if(inCode) {
                isChange = true;
                out += "AS $" + "$\n";
            }
        }
        if (endCode.test(lines[i])){
            out += "$" + "$;";
            isChange = true;
            inCode = false;
        }
        if(!isChange){
            if(inCode){
                s = lines[i].replace(/''/g, "'") + "\n";
                s = s.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
                out += s;
            } else {
                out += lines[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
$$;
```

You can then call the UDF by wrapping it around the get_ddl function. Here is an example of fishing its own DDL out of get_ddl:

```
select CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(get_ddl('function', 'CODE_DDL_TO_TEXT(string)'));
```

Edit:

You can also use this SQL to reconstruct a stored procedure from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
select  'create or replace procedure ' || PROCEDURE_NAME || ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE || 
        '\nreturns ' || DATA_TYPE || 
        '\nlanguage ' || PROCEDURE_LANGUAGE || 
        '\nas $' || '$\n' || 
        PROCEDURE_DEFINITION || 
        '\n$' || '$;'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES
;
```

Comment: I tried this out, and the result still has some extra single quotes. Thank you for trying

Comment: If you can share the code (or section of it that the UDF did not correct), I can check on this.

Comment: The edit did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This only returns body -

SELECT PROCEDURE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES
WHERE PROCEDURE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND PROCEDURE_NAME = upper('stack_overflow_question');

Comment: This would have been perfect if it returned more than the definition. I will keep this in my toolbelt!

Comment: @alexspurlock25 you can extend that query to reconstruct the entire stored procedure. I edited my answer to show this.